# CoffeeScript function parentheses

Tags: coffeescript

I'm just learning CoffeeScript and I'm trying to do something I would normally do in plain 'ol JavaScript.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
initializeWebGL = (canvas) ->
    gl = canvas.getContext "webgl" or canvas.getContext "experimental-webgl"
```

Which compiles to what I kind of expect:

```
var initializeWebGL;

initializeWebGL = function(canvas) {
  var gl;
  return gl = canvas.getContext("webgl" || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl"));
};
```

In order to get what I *really* want, I have to wrap the `getContext` arguments with parentheses:

```
initializeWebGL = (canvas) ->
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") or canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl")
```

Which produces what I want:

```
var initializeWebGL;

initializeWebGL = function(canvas) {
  var gl;
  return gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
};
```

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve than to just add parentheses around the function calls like in the second example?

Comment: I (almost) always include the parentheses when calling a function, that way I don't have to mentally parse the code to know what it is doing: the parentheses increase readability and readability is far more important than orthodoxy. In your specific case, if you don't like how CoffeeScript interprets your code then add parentheses to force the issue, that's what they're for.

Comment: Just because Coffeescript is smart enough to identify function arguments (in many cases), does not mean that you are (or will be when you maintain the code 6 months from now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve than to just add parentheses around the function calls like in the second example?

No, I don't think so. My rule of thumb is it's OK to omit parentheses when the function call and its arguments are the last thing on a line, otherwise include them.

#### OK

```
someFunction 1, 2, 3
```

#### Not OK

```
someFunction 1, someOtherFunction 2, 3
```

In general I try to avoid overly-concise, terse statements. They are harder to work with both mentally as well as stepping through in a debugger is trickier.

Comment: You should also avoid somefunction 1, 2 .callback (para) as it would try to run the callback on 2. had this working with promises/ .then.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say it's a better way but you could do something like this:

```
initializeWebGL = (canvas) ->
  gl = canvas.getContext "webgl"
  gl = gl or canvas.getContext "experimental-webgl"
```

I personally prefer readability over writing less code:

```
initializeWebGL = (canvas) ->
  gl = canvas.getContext "webgl"
  if !gl? then gl = canvas.getContext "experimental-webgl"
```

Comment: It depends what is 'readbility'. It's highly subjective. The second example is for example much more readable for me than first one.